# How to set @HostBinding for conditions in angular component

Tags: angular

I want to set @HostBinding for specific conditions only. Suppose that I declared the @HostBinding like below in angular component

```
@Input() @HostBinding('innerHTML') mainvalue;
```

if the **mainvalue** is empty or undefined, then how can we stop working hostbinding?. currently if **mainvalue** is empty or undefined, then whole content of the component is going to deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923564/conditional-hostbinding-depending-on-input

Answer (score 3):

Use a setter on your input to conditionally set or keep your innerHTML host binding:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: '',
})
export class TestComponent {

  @Input() set mainValue (value: any) {
    if (value) {
      this.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
    }
    // otherwise keep the current innerHTML
  }

  @HostBinding('innerHTML') innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ngIf directive to conditionally apply the host binding only when the mainvalue is defined and not empty.
<ng-container *ngIf="mainvalue">
@Input() @HostBinding('innerHTML') mainvalue;
`enter code here`